# Merge Two Mongodb Collections and select unique values (pymongo)

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a collection of questions , and a collection of sales in both collections i have a field called item_id

I need to generate a list with the unique items id on each collection

Example :

orders collection :

```
{
"orderid": 1
"itemid": item1
},
{
"orderid": 2
"itemid": item2
},
{
"orderid": 3
"itemid": item4
}
```

questions collection :

```
{
"questionid":1
"itemid":item1
},
{
"questionid":2
"itemid":item2
},
{
"questionid":3
"itemid":item3
}
```

The result im looking for is something like this

items collection :

```
{
"itemid":item1,
"itemid":item2,
"itemid":item3,
"itemid":item4,
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get distinct items from collection by using: `col.distict('itemid')`

And then aggregate items in a set data structure.

```
all_items = set()
orders = db.orders.distinct('itemid')
questions = db.questions.distinct('itemid')
for item in orders:
    all_items.add(item)
for item in questions:
    all_items.add(item)
```

At the end all_items is a set containing distinct items from both collections and you can convert it to any other data structure as you need.

```
#inserting to item collection
col = db.items
for item in all_items:
    col.insert_one({'item' : item})
```

Adding items to a set, guarantees uniqueness of elements.